# Как сравнить переменную со списком комманд?

Tags: python, python-3.6

Есть список, в этом списке лежат команды

`joke = ['Команда 1', 'Команда 2', 'Команда 3']`

И есть переменная, эта переменная команда от пользователя.

`answ = input(">")`

Как можно сравнить ответ пользователя с каждой из данных команд?

Comment: что значит сравнить? узнать, что введенная команда есть в списке или узнать индекс команды в списке?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ваш код. Всё очень просто...

```
joke = ['Команда 1', 'Команда 2', 'Команда 3']
answ = input(">")
if answ in joke:
    #ваш код
    #не сомневайтесь, что в answ содержится 1 из 3 команд
```

Comment: Спасибо вам, большое!

Comment: Поставьте галочку)